# According to Dvaita, are there puranic examples where Ishwara(God) or anyone(Sages and Saints) who has turned anybody's Jeevatma into Jada?

Tags: ramayana, vedanta, dvaita, ahalya

As random as the question may seem, it was the response of a person, from Dvaitha school, to my question can God convert Jeeva into Jada?

And he said "coming to your question of if Paramatma can turn Jada to jeeva, I confirmed it with the person who has done sudha paata, yep it's possible, the story of ahalya is the best example, of many, where in she was turned into a Stone by a curse from her husband and then into a jeeva by Rama just by a brush if his feet. Stone is nothing but a Jada, so this Leela of Paramatma turning jeeva into Jada and vice versa is possible only by his sankalpa."

I tried to explain him that Atma is Jeeva and Body is Jada. Even now human body is Jada. So Ahalya's Jada body was converted into Jada stone back to human body, while all along the soul of Ahalya lived and experienced the pain of living in a rock, until liberated by Shri Rama. And if at all her soul was converted into Jada, she would experience nothing, as Jada according to Dwaita is non sentient. So it would not at all be a punishment. It will be like a time travel to her. So her soul had to be present in order for it to be a punishment.

Whether God can convert Jeeva into Jada or not is another point. But was Ahalya's soul converted into Jada ? I think the answer is no. And more over if that happened Dwaiti's can't argue for Athyanthik bhedha or eternal difference, as it has already been violated once. Clearly even Dwaita people will not accept this. But the person who gave this answer said he got this from the person who had Sudha Patha. So now I'm totally confused.

Answer only according to Dwaitha view, whether Ahalya's soul was converted into Jada ? or it was only body that was converted into stone, which was already Jada so there was no conversion?

---

**Edit: It has been brought to my notice that Ahalya was actually [made invisible](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=48&field_sloka_value=29) instead of being turned into a stone and it is suggested to use the story of [Rambha](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=64&field_sloka_value=12) in its place as it fits better. You can answer using any story as an example, but the main point of the question is, according to Dvaita, are there puranic examples where Ishwara(God) or anyone(Sages and Saints) who has turned anybody's Jeevatma into Jada? If No alright, if Yes, where is the source?, how will you reconcile the punishment aspect as Jada cannot feel anything? and also how will you reconcile the Athyanthika Bhedha aspect which is at the foundation of the philosophy?**

Comment: Seriously, no answer...?

Comment: When you can apply in ahalya case  that is not turned into rock just made invisible same tihng canbe made out here.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this question from a different discussion you are having elsewhere.
Shri Madhvacharya says the following in his anuvyAkhyaana --
na chetanavikAraH syAd.h yatra kvApi hyachetanam |
nAchetanavikAro.api chetanaH syAt kadAchana

In simple terms, a chetana never morphs to become an achetana i.e. jaDa and vice-versa. This is in the fourth pada of first adhyaaya of Brahmasutras, where he is refuting the idea of Brahman is the material cause (upaadaana kaaraNa) of the world. He examines the stock examples of spider weaving the web, and holds that none of examples talk of Brahman being the upaadaana karana.